# Street address verification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xmlhttprequest, nsurlrequest

My user enters a recipients address (Street address not email). I need to verify it with the USPS so I know that it is actually an address.

I am digging through their API right now and I think I understand it but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it with objective-c.

So pretty much it works like so:

1. I have to create an XML request that contains the recipient name, address, and zip code.
2. I have to post that to their server
3. They respond with an XML response

Here is an example of what one of their constructed XML request looks like:

```
http://SERVERNAME/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest% 20USERID="xxxxxxx"><Address ID="0"><Address1></Address1>
<Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State> <Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>
```

A bit garbled but broken down:

```
http://SERVERNAME/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=
<AddressValidateRequest% 20USERID="xxxxxxx">
  <Address ID="0">
    <Address1></Address1>
     <Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2>
     <City>Greenbelt</City>
     <State>MD</State>
     <Zip5></Zip5>
     <Zip4></Zip4>
  </Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>
```

My first idea seems obvious but there maybe a better way to go about it. Since the XML feed short, should I go about construction by simple doing something along the lines of:

NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"......"]

Where it is filled in and formatted along the lines posted above.

The second question is how to go about correctly sending this to the server?

I simply create a NSURL request and with the URL as the constructed XML string?

Here what I have but I keep getting that the URL was constructed wrong:

```
- (void)verifyAddress:(Recipient*)_recipient {

    NSURL *_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID=\"********\"><Address ID=\"0\"><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>"];

    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"the response '%@'", newStr);
    } else {
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
        NSLog(@"error");
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{


    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the response '%@'", newStr);
    // do something with the data
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Connection failed! Error - bad URL (null)
```

My only question now is, am I doing everything ok as far as NSURLConnection goes? I can play around with the URL, I just want to make sure my implementation is ok so Im not running around in circles. :P

Answer (score 1):

You have `% 20` in your URL.  It should be `%20` (no space).

There may be other problems, but that was one was easy to spot.  If you are getting an error message, you need to edit your question and paste in the *exact* error message.

Also, you might consider using Apple's `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` classes, because more people are likely to be familiar with them so it may be easier for you to find help.

Comment: You are not using `NSURLConnection` correctly.  Please read *[Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)* in the *URL Loading System Programming Guide*.

Answer (score 1):

Cory, I work in the address validation industry (for [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), where what you're trying to do is our specialty in fact) and have seen a lot of similar issues to yours.

We actually used to support an XML-endpoint for our address verification API ([LiveAddress](https://smartystreets.com/products)). Last year we deprecated it and deployed a new JSON format because the XML was clunky to use and had a lot of problems when it's actually just a simple task (for you, the developer).

So a few things to keep in mind... and while Rob's answer is programmatically comprehensive, these are important to consider also:

- The USPS is the official source of addresses for the USA, but its core domain is *not* providing API service. Especially with recent financial troubles, I suspect that support and maintenance of the API will wane over time.
- The [License Agreement](https://secure.shippingapis.com/registration/) for the API you're using is quite restrictive. For example:

  > User agrees to use the USPS Web site, APIs and USPS data to facilitate USPS shipping transactions only. [27 Jan 2012]

  Meaning, if you're shipping mail or packages via the USPS by using their API, it's fine, but for any other purpose it's not allowed and it violates the TOS.
- I see you're developing for iOS. There's a *great* JSON library for that called [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) that, in my opinion, is easier to use than XML formats in Objective-C.

While the USPS service does work, they CASS-certify private entities to provide their data at a better value (more specialty, experience, features, etc).

These and other maladies can be remedied by service from a third-party vendor. More details and reasons are [documented here](https://smartystreets.com/articles/usps-api). Which provider you choose is up to you, but I'll be happy to personally answer any other address-validation-related questions.

Comment: We are in fact using USPS to ship items so we are ok with their TOS. I have SmartyStreets before and it is an excellent site/application but we are on a shoe-string budget and need something free (USPS). Thank you for the reference to TouchJSON, I will take a look and see if it helps!